# How to know that a JS event listener is registered on the native end?

Tags: react-native

I have a native module that emits an event, and it is vital that my app gets every instance of that event to stay properly in sync.

However, the following code is prone to race conditions:

```
new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.MyModule).addEventListener("x", f)
NativeModules.MyModule.start()
```

`addEventListener` requires an asynchronous call over the bridge from JS to native, so it's possible that `MyModule` starts emitting events before the event listener is completely registered, causing my app to miss out on important events.

Is there a way to know from the JS side when an `addEventListener` has completed registering? If so, I can wait with calling `.start()` until I know that the event listener is completely registered.

Answer (score 0):

> Native modules can also fulfill a promise, which can simplify your
>   code, especially when using ES2016's async/await syntax.

Read further [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios#promises) for iOS, and [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#promises) for Android.

Comment: The problem is with the call to `addEventListener` - I need to know when it is registered, and there's no promise returned or callback to be sent in to know when that has happened

Comment: I see. you are right, the bridge is async and addEventListener doesn't resolve a promise or invokes a callback when done. Or at least I don't know of it.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by implementing my own event dispatching on top of the existing one.

On the iOS side, you have to create an RCTEventEmitter that notifies JS when it has a subscriber.

```c
// -------------------
// MyEventModule.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyEventModule :  RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>
-(void)sendMyEventWithName:(NSString*)name body:(id)body NS_SWIFT_NAME(sendMyEvent(name:body:));
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

// -------------------
// MyEventModule.m
#import "MyEventModule.h"

@implementation MyEventModule
{
    bool hasListeners;
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents
{
    return @[@"myEvent"];
}

-(void)startObserving {
    hasListeners = YES;
    [self sendMyEventWithName:@"myEventInitialized" body:@{}];
}

-(void)stopObserving {
    hasListeners = NO;
}

- (void)sendMyEventWithName:(NSString *)name body:(id)body {
    if (!hasListeners) {
        // You'll get a warning if you send events from native when there
        // are no listeners yet.
        return;
    }

    [self sendEventWithName:@"myEvent" body:@{@"name": name, @"body": body}];
}
@end
```

On Android, no special work is needed, since all events seem to be sent all the time, and there's no async stuff happening under the hood - the subscription is simply a JS-side thing that adds a listener to an event that JS would already get. So all you need is a stub module so that JS won't blow up on Android.

```
class MyEventModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {
    override fun getName(): String {
        return "MyEventModule"
    }

}
```

On the JS side, you can now do something like this:

```js
import {NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules, Platform} from "react-native"

type EventHandler = (e: any) => void

export default class MyEventEmitter {
    private readonly isReadyResolvers: (() => void)[] = []
    private _isReady: boolean = false
    private readonly eventHandlers: {[key: string]: (EventHandler)[]} = {}

    constructor() {
        const myNativeEventEmitterModule = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.MyEventModule)

        myNativeEventEmitterModule.addListener("myEvent", (e: {name: string, body: any}) => {
            if (e.name === "myEventInitialized") {
                this._isReady = true
                this.isReadyResolvers.forEach(it => it())
                this.isReadyResolvers.length = 0
            } else {
                const listeners = this.eventHandlers[e.name]
                listeners && listeners.forEach(it => it(e.body))
            }
        })

        // Android does not need async event setup
        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
            this._isReady = true
        }
    }

    addListener(event: string, handler: EventHandler) {
        this.eventHandlers[event] = this.eventHandlers[event] || []
        this.eventHandlers[event].push(handler)
    }

    removeListener(event: string, handler: EventHandler) {
        const listeners = this.eventHandlers[event]
        const idx = listeners.indexOf(handler)
        if (idx >= 0) {
            listeners.splice(idx, 1)
        }
    }

    removeAllListeners(event: string) {
        delete this.eventHandlers[event]
    }

    isReady(): Promise<any> {
        if (this._isReady) {
            return Promise.resolve()
        } else {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.isReadyResolvers.push(resolve)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to create a new `MyEventEmitter`, subscribe to events, and get a way to wait for it to be all set up and ready to receive events.

```js
const em = new MyEventEmitter()
em.isReady().then(() => {
  em.addListener("whatever", (e) => {
    // Do  your thing
  })
})
```

The tricky part is to have `MyEventModule` being accessible to the rest of the app. I settled on initializing it manually in the RCTBridgeDelegate and storing it on the app delegate.